# How to use the ASP.NET Core membership tables navigation properties with default identity configured?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project with Default Identity and configured it as follows:

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>
```

I already have the generated ApplicationDBContext:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

In the same context class, I added my own domain tables. In addition, I modified the `OnModelBuilder` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // my code for other entities not AspNet* 
}
```

What I want to do is to have the `AspNet*` tables in the application model so I can use the navigation properties of another tables to arrive at the specific `AspNet*` table.

I tried manually adding the `AspNet*` tables in the context but I do get some exceptions as they overlap with existing model built by Identity (which is however under the hood...)

What is the best way for me to include and reference the `AspNet*` tables in addition to using the default identity model.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added your own fields to the default structure of Identity? What are your specific needs?

Comment: @Chaodeng: I did not added. I just want to use what identity already brings in terms of models and service classes in order to use users and roles for authentication/authorization.

Comment: @Chaodeng: I do not want however the use the UI pages it brings..so I don't use services.AddDefaultIdentitiy but services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>